# Slicing multidimensional numpy array to obtain a vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

In this example I'm trying to create a vector by selecting relevant elements from a multidimensional array.

```
#data
n=3
rng = 4
x = np.array([0,1,2],dtype=int)
y = np.array([0,3,1],dtype=int)
P = np.reshape(np.arange(n*rng*rng),(n,rng,rng))

output = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    output[i] = P[i,x[i],y[i]]
```

This returns

```
array([  0.,  23.,  41.])
```

Now I'm trying to vectorize the above operation. To me, the logical thing would be to set

```
output = P[0:n,x,y]
```

but this returns

```
array([[ 0,  7,  9],
       [16, 23, 25],
       [32, 39, 41]])
```

Can anybody explain what is going on here and what I should do to obtain the intended output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
>>> P[np.arange(n), x, y]
array([ 0, 23, 41])
```

Related: [Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Been struggling with this all day.